# Condition WHERE string without/with space

Tags: string, t-sql, where-clause, space

I have table with some strings. I would like make select with condition string = eqauls something
I Dont have any other strings....
The select returns more rows when I Have:
What is wrong?

```
DECLARE @C VARCHAR(2) = 'A'+SPACE(1)
DECLARE @T TABLE (id INT NOT NULL, string VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL)
INSERT INTO @T
(
    id,
    string
)
VALUES
(   1,    'A'), (2,'A'+SPACE(1))


SELECT * FROM @T WHERE string = @C--With space only
```

Returns:

```
id  string
1   A
2   A
```

I know hot to make select LIKE '%.... '.
I want to know why TSQL returns more rows.

SQL 2019, MSSQL version 18.9.2

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/10510/7656

Comment: see [how-sql-server-compares-strings-with-trailing-spaces](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/inf-how-sql-server-compares-strings-with-trailing-spaces-b62b1a2d-27d3-4260-216d-a605719003b0)

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server follows the ANSI standard when it comes to comparing strings with `=`. Read a longer description over here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10511/7656

The bottom line is, you can't check for trailing spaces with `=`. Use `LIKE` without any `%` instead.

Given

```
CREATE TABLE T (id INT NOT NULL, string VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL)
INSERT INTO T VALUES (1, 'A')
INSERT INTO T VALUES (2, 'A ')
```

this

```
SELECT id, len(string) len, datalength(string) datalength FROM T
```

results in

| id | len | datalength |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |

and

```
SELECT id FROM T WHERE string LIKE 'A '
```

will give you `2`. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2356c9/1

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the following solutions

```
-- Option 1: add to the filter the condition `DATALENGTH(@C) = DATALENGTH(string)` or 'DATALENGTH(@C) < DATALENGTH(string)'
SELECT * FROM @T WHERE string = @C and DATALENGTH(@C) <= DATALENGTH(string)

-- Option 2: Use `LIKE` and add the expresion '%'
SELECT * FROM @T WHERE string like @C + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `=` operator ignores trailing spaces just like `LEN()`. The `LIKE` operator does not

```
SELECT * FROM @T WHERE string LIKE @C
```

You can prove this with

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 'A' = 'A ' THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END -- True
SELECT CASE WHEN 'A' = ' A' THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END -- False because of leading space
SELECT CASE WHEN 'A' LIKE 'A ' THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END -- False
SELECT LEN(string), FROM @T -- both return 1
```